# Changing classes to another name so it doesn't activate onClick in jquery, then reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

#### Background

I am trying to create a jquery function which will change all class names EXCEPT the current object in question, execute a function, and then reset all old classes back, dynamically, without refresh... Anyone know how I can acheive this?

#### HTML

```
<div class="view_link">
    <a href="#" class="edit_link" data-link="edit_input_a">Edit</a>
    <span class="edit_input_a"><input type='text' name='input' /></span>
</div>        
<div class="view_link">
    <a href="#" class="edit_link" data-link="edit_input_z">Edit</a>
    <span class="edit_input_z"><input type='text' name='input' /></span>
</div>
<div class="view_link">
    <a href="#" class="edit_link" data-link="edit_input_9">Edit</a>
    <span class="edit_input_9"><input type='text' name='input' /></span>
</div>
```

#### Javascript

```
$('.edit_link').click(function(e) {
    //set which fields to act upon
    var edit_field = $(this).data('link');
    //Open the editable field of the corresponding item
    $("." + edit_field).slideDown(700,'linear');

    /* now change all the other a links with class 'edit_link' to edit_link_inactive (EXCEPT THE CURRENT OBJECT BEING WORKED ON) so if the user clicks another link at the same time, it will not run through the click function */

   //Run Ajax Function

   /* On succeed, reset all classes with 'edit_link_inactive' back to edit_link */
```

#### Not Working Statement That I've Tried

```
$('.edit_link').not(this).attr('class', "inactive");
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Is your "Not Working Statement That I've Tried" inside the `success` of an AJAX call? In that case, `this` isn't what you think it is

Comment: @ian no, I have not even created the ajax yet...as of right now its jquery only

Comment: Instead of using `.attr()` for this, maybe you want to use `.addClass("inactive")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the class at a later time does not remove event handlers that are already attached to the element, you'll need to use `off()` for that:

```
$('.edit_link').on('click', doStuff);

function doStuff(e) {
    var edit_field = $(this).data('link');
    $("." + edit_field).slideDown(700,'linear');
    ....

    $('.edit_link').not(this).off('click', doStuff);

    $.ajax({
        ......
    }).always(function() {
         $('.edit_link').on('click', doStuff);
    })
}
```

Comment: could this design be used in combination with the class set/reset?  because this is mainly a multilevel view modal->display dynamic info-> on edit click ->show fields/submit dynamically ->reset modal to original view

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but I think you're trying to change the class so that the function you bound to that class is no longer attached, and that won't work, as once the event handler is attached, changing the class does not "unattach" it.

Comment: Although I'm sure this solution works, wouldn't it make more sense to just bind one event to a container and use event delegation? That way, the handler won't execute if the element doesn't have a certain class (if the concept of classes was still used).

Comment: @adeneo  yeap!  dead on target...   im slightly new to jquery, would you mind commenting to code so i can fully understand its functionality?

Comment: @Ian - Yes, delegating the event would work as well, as that would check the target for a certain class etc. without having to remove the event handler.

Comment: @adeneo aren't we also missing an original bracket for the opening of `doStuff(e) {`

Comment: @hawkhorrow - not anymore ;.)

Comment: Since you both seem to understand what I am trying to acheive here, would you say that an event handler would be a better implementation? or adeneos alternative?

Comment: @adeneo why would `.always(function() { $on.('click', doStuff)}` need a designation back to the original dostuff function?  because essentially that ajax function would be self contained inside itself, therefore make an infinite loop?

Comment: It reattaches the event that was removed with off(), and does'nt cause a loop.

Comment: @adeneo ok... last question, would you recommend declaring that function inside of the actual click function?  where would I insert the code in your implementation for most effectiveness?

Comment: That depends on the expected functionality. To remove the event handler and reattach it after the ajax call has completed, you'll have to do it somewhat similar to the above, as the ajax call is async.

Comment: @adeneo ah, so I could declare the function and ajax call as standard js, and then use the `$('.edit_link').on('click', doStuff);` actually inside of the `.click` function?

Comment: @adeneo my mistake, functionality error attributed to using an older version of the jquery library... in 1.9.1 and jsfiddle, it works http://jsfiddle.net/WRD4J/